# VBA EGe error message rom Execute SP

Tags: vba, stored-procedures

I have an Excel macro that executes a Stored Procedure (SQL2008 R2). The SP has  lot of error handling and rises lots of custom errors. Is there a way to get these back to VBA without using an Output parameter (assuming that would work). All I ever get back is error no -6

Here's my code snippet

```
       ' Call the SP
        Dim iReturn As Integer
        iReturn = 0
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "EPMS_CreateInvoice"
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("iReturn", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SGInvID", adInteger, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@InvDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@PostDate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CSR", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SalesRep", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@BillerInitials", adVarChar, adParamInput, 4)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Terms", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@InvNo", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@CustomerID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20)
        cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Draft", adBoolean, adParamInput)



        iReturn = cmd.Parameters(iReturn)
        cmd.Parameters("@SGInvID") = SGInvID
        cmd.Parameters("@InvDate") = InvoiceDate
        cmd.Parameters("@PostDate") = PostingDate
        cmd.Parameters("@CSR") = CSR
        cmd.Parameters("@SalesRep") = SalesRep
        cmd.Parameters("@BillerInitials") = BillerInitials
        cmd.Parameters("@Terms") = TermsCode
        cmd.Parameters("@InvNo") = InvoiceNo
        cmd.Parameters("@CustomerID") = CustomerID
        cmd.Parameters("@Draft") = Draft
```

Thanks

Mark

Comment: I obviously don't know what your SP might do, but is it not possible to take the majority of the error-handling out of the stored procedure?

Comment: If you're using ADO have you tried checking the connection's `Errors` collection: http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_error.asp  ?

Comment: Andy, thanks for reply, but the SP implements a lot of biz logic, so moving to VBA is not practical

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Tim Williams was what I was looking for:

If you're using ADO have you tried checking the connection's Errors collection: w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_error.asp ?